# Coinbase Pay does not compile, missing babel loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to integrate with the coinbase pay sdk.  I've created a button using their examples, however when trying to build I'm getting an issue **Internal to their SDK**

When trying to build my code I get an error internal to the `@coinbase/cbpay-js sdk

> ./node_modules/@coinbase/cbpay-js/dist/index.mjs 135:34 Module parse
> failed: Unexpected token (135:34) File was processed with these
> loaders:  * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js You may need an
> additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. | var
> isMobileSdkTarget = /* @**PURE** */__name(win => { |   try {
>
> > ```
> > return win.ReactNativeWebView?.postMessage !== void 0; |   } catch { |     return false;
> > ```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "React App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arkane-network/web3-arkane-provider": "^0.23.0",
    "@ethersproject/experimental": "^5.4.0",
    "@gelatonetwork/limit-orders-react": "^2.4.0",
    "@gnosis.pm/safe-apps-sdk": "^4.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.3.5",
    "@transak/transak-sdk": "^1.0.28",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/multicodec": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.7",
    "@types/react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@types/testing-library__cypress": "^5.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.3.1",
    "@uniswap/governance": "^1.0.2",
    "@uniswap/liquidity-staker": "^1.0.2",
    "@uniswap/merkle-distributor": "1.0.1",
    "@uniswap/sdk": "npm:quickswap-sdk@3.0.8",
    "@uniswap/token-lists": "npm:quickswap-token-lists@1.0.1",
    "@uniswap/v2-core": "1.0.0",
    "@uniswap/v2-periphery": "^1.1.0-beta.0",
    "@web3-react/core": "6.0.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "6.0.7",
    "@web3-react/ledger-connector": "6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/portis-connector": "6.0.9",
    "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector": "6.2.4",
    "@web3-react/walletlink-connector": "6.2.3",
    "ajv": "^6.12.3",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "cids": "^1.1.9",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.2.0",
    "cypress": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "ethers": "^5.0.7",
    "fortmatic": "^2.2.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.4.1",
    "i18next": "^20.4.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "ipfs-deploy": "^11.1.0",
    "lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.0",
    "multicodec": "^3.0.1",
    "multihashes": "^3.0.1",
    "polished": "^3.3.2",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.8",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.6",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "redux-localstorage-simple": "^2.4.1",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web3": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "yargs-parser": "^13.1.2",
    "underscore": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "trim-newlines": "^3.0.1",
    "nth-check": "^2.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "follow-redirects": "^1.14.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.2",
    "immer": "^9.0.6",
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.8",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.0",
    "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.5",
    "ajv": "^6.12.3",
    "async": "^3.2.2",
    "ejs": "^3.1.7",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "eventsource": "^2.0.2",
    "protobufjs": "^6.11.3",
    "shell-quote": "^1.7.3",
    "terser": "^4.8.1",
    "got": "^11.8.5",
    "jpeg-js": "^0.4.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "CI=false react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,js,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "integration-test": "start-server-and-test 'serve build -l 3000' http://localhost:3000 'cypress run'",
    "ipfs-deploy": "ipfs-deploy build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "dependencies": {
    "@coinbase/cbpay-js": "^1.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "apexcharts": "3.32.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "market-sdk": "^2.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "1.3.9",
    "react-cool-inview": "^2.0.8",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-query": "^3.34.19",
    "react-reflex": "^4.0.6",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-virtuoso": "^2.8.4",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Configuration Overrides:

```
const {paths} = require('react-app-rewired');
// load environment variables from .env files
// before overrides scripts are read
require(paths.scriptVersion + '/config/env');
const override = require(paths.configOverrides);

const webpack = typeof override === 'function'
  ? override
  : override.webpack || ((config, env) => config);

if (override.devserver) {
  console.log(
    'Warning: `devserver` has been deprecated. Please use `devServer` instead as ' +
    '`devserver` will not be used in the next major release.'
  )
}

const devServer = override.devServer || override.devserver
  || ((configFunction) =>
    (proxy, allowedHost) =>
      configFunction(proxy, allowedHost));

const jest = override.jest || ((config) => config);

const pathsOverride = override.paths || ((paths, env) => paths);

// normalized overrides functions
module.exports = {
  webpack,
  devServer,
  jest,
  paths: pathsOverride
};
```

I'm guessing I'm missing a dependecy for a babel loader or something, but I'm not sure how to figure out which one I need?

Comment: Can you share webpack/babel config and package json to see what versions that you used?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I've added the package.json,  no webpack

Comment: I see `.mjs` in the dist code. I wonder if that means you need to add `type: "module"` to your package.json (which would impact which module flavor you can use in your own code).

Comment: @Tom thanks ill try that, do I just add that at the root level?

Comment: Yes, `type` is a top-level property in package.json.

Comment: @Tom I think your on to the right idea, however when I do that it breaks all the files that use a .js extension

Comment: Yeah, so, that means you need to change all your module syntax. Alternatively, you could just install the babel plugin that transforms everything to commonjs.

Comment: Looks like you app was created by create-react app and you also override the config with react-wired. Can you share this file `config-overrides.js` as well?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I've added the overrides as well

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit workaround rather that the correct way, but after day of investigation I've just changed in my code

```
import { initOnRamp } from '@coinbase/cbpay-js';
```

to

```
import { initOnRamp } from '@coinbase/cbpay-js/dist/index.js';
```

And it worked for me